# Extract only text from div tags on a page using Python and Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a static news website as a project, I am using Beautiful soup , but I am stuck on a page which contains text in div tag , here text means the news article

the link for the site is 
http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/magazines/panache/smoking-aces-chef-irshad-qureshis-interesting-stories-related-to-celebrities/articleshow/48712333.cms

The news text is contained in a below format

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="normal" id="foo">
      " Many "
 <a href ='/some link' target = 'blank'>Bollywood</a>
 " stars today  are avowed foodies "
 <a href = 'link2'>Ranbir Kapoor</a>
 " Alia Bhat "
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The text I want is "**Many Bollywood stars today are vowed foodies. Alia Bhat**"

That is I want all the text wherever they are.

I was able to arrrive at div using find_all('div','normal'), but stuck how to retrieve all the text elements from page after that.

Please let me know if you want any more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the `text` from some element in beautifulsoup you can use the `.text` attribute:

```
>>> t  = """<div class="normal" id="foo">  Many  <a href ='/some link' target = 'blank'>Bollywood</a>  stars today  are avowed foodies  <a href = 'link2'>Ranbir Kapoor</a>  Alia Bhat  </div>"""
>>> bs = BeautifulSoup(t)
>>> print(bs.find('div').text)
  Many  Bollywood  stars today  are avowed foodies  Ranbir Kapoor  Alia Bhat
```